# linux: traffic shaping per TCP session

Tags: linux, tcp, trafficshaping

I'm running a service on TCP port 7070 and  i want to limit the incoming and/or outgoing traffic to f.e. 50kbits/s. The limit should be per TCP session whatever the src ip is.

Can you please send me any hints how I can build this?

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Michael